# Understanding ARMv7 seemingly overly verbose disassembly

Tags: disassembly, arm

I’m working with a disassembled ARMv7 binary. There are several instances where groups of instructions seem sub-optimal, but this one really caught my attention:

```
00009086         movw       r3, #0x4f36
0000908a         movt       r3, #0x1                                            ; ledTimer
0000908e         ldrh       r3, [r3]                                            ; ledTimer
00009090         subs       r3, #0x1
00009092         uxth       r2, r3
00009094         movw       r3, #0x4f36
00009098         movt       r3, #0x1                                            ; ledTimer
0000909c         strh       r2, [r3]                                            ; ledTimer
0000909e         movw       r3, #0x4f36
000090a2         movt       r3, #0x1                                            ; ledTimer
000090a6         ldrh       r3, [r3]                                            ; ledTimer
000090a8         cmp        r3, #0x0
000090aa         bne.w      loc_9250
```

Since `loc_9250` is the beginning of the epilogue, I interpreted this section as:

```
if (--ledTimer != 0) {
    return;
}
```

Am I missing something about the ARMv7 architecture that makes all these instructions necessary (besides my disassembler not substituting the pseudo-`mov32` for the `movw`/`movt` pairs)? It seems like a very inefficient way of going about this sequence of operations. Or perhaps this is just the result of a compiler with optimisation settings cranked right down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably because `*ledTimer` is volatile.  Here's a short bit of code that produces a similar result:

```
int main() {
    volatile unsigned short *ledTimer{(unsigned short *)0x14f36};
    for (--(*ledTimer); *ledTimer; --(*ledTimer));
}
```

Now compile with gcc 8.3.1 with `-march=armv7 -O1` and we get something that starts to resemble what you've listed:

```
main:
        movw    r2, #20278
        movt    r2, 1
        ldrh    r3, [r2]
        subs    r3, r3, #1
        uxth    r3, r3
        strh    r3, [r2]        @ movhi
        ldrh    r3, [r2]
        uxth    r3, r3
        cbz     r3, .L2
        movw    r2, #20278
        movt    r2, 1
.L3:
        ldrh    r3, [r2]
        subs    r3, r3, #1
        uxth    r3, r3
        strh    r3, [r2]        @ movhi
        ldrh    r3, [r2]
        uxth    r3, r3
        cmp     r3, #0
        bne     .L3
.L2:
        movs    r0, #0
        bx      lr
```

You can [try it live](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/nseG19).

Comment: This is just the kind of insight I was looking for, thank you! I hope you don’t mind if I wait a day or so to accept your answer, just in case someone else has other ideas.

Comment: No, I don't mind at all.  Others may very well provide more detailed answers or create code that exactly matches what you've disassembled.  Glad I could be of help!